# Is there any difference between return n and exit(n) in C?

Tags: c, standards

Is there any difference between `return n` (in the `main` function) and `exit(n)` in C? Is it defined by C or POSIX standards or it depends on OS or compiler?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In most cases, there's no difference, but here's a C program that's likely to behave differently depending on whether it uses `return 0;` or `exit(0);`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char *message;

void cleanup(void) {
    printf("message = \"%s\"\n", message);
}

int main(void) {
    char local_message[] = "hello, world";
    message = local_message;
    atexit(cleanup);
#ifdef USE_EXIT
    puts("exit(0);");
    exit(0);
#else
    puts("return 0;");
    return 0;
#endif
}
```

Because of the `atexit()` call, either `exit(0);` or `return 0;` causes the `cleanup` function to be invoked. The difference is that if the program calls `exit(0);`, the cleanup happens while the "call" to `main()` is still active, so the `local_message` object still exists. Executing `return 0;`, however, immediately terminates the invocation of `main()` and *then* invokes the `cleanup()` function. Since `cleanup()` refers (via the global `message` pointer) to an object that's allocated locally to `main`, and that object no longer exists, the behavior is undefined.

Here's the behavior I see on my system:

```
$ gcc -DUSE_EXIT c.c -o c && ./c
exit(0);
message = "hello, world"
$ gcc c.c -o c && ./c
return 0;
message = ""
$
```

Running the program without `-DUSE_EXIT` could do anything, including crashing or printing `"hello, world"` (if the memory used by `local_message` happens not to be clobbered).

In practice, though, this difference only shows up if objects defined locally inside `main()` are made visible outside `main()` by saving pointers to them. This could plausibly happen for `argv`. (Experiment on my system shows that the objects pointed to by `argv` and by `*argv` continue to exist after returning from `main()`, but you shouldn't depend on that.)

Answer (score 18):

- **For C**
  The Standard says that a return from the initial call to main is equivalent to calling exit. However, a return from main cannot be expected to work if data local to main might be needed during cleanup.
- **For C++**

When exit(0) is used to exit from program, destructors for locally scoped non-static objects are not called. But destructors are called if return 0 is used.

Program 1 – - uses exit(0) to exit

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
  Test() {
    printf("Inside Test's Constructor\n");
  }

  ~Test(){
    printf("Inside Test's Destructor");
    getchar();
  }
};

int main() {
  Test t1;

  // using exit(0) to exit from main
  exit(0);
}
```

Output:
Inside Test’s Constructor

Program 2 – uses return 0 to exit

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
  Test() {
    printf("Inside Test's Constructor\n");
  }

  ~Test(){
    printf("Inside Test's Destructor");
  }
};

int main() {
  Test t1;

   // using return 0 to exit from main
  return 0;
}
```

Output:
Inside Test’s Constructor
Inside Test’s Destructor

Calling destructors is sometimes important, for example, if destructor has code to release resources like closing files.

Note that static objects will be cleaned up even if we call exit(). For example, see following program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
  Test() {
    printf("Inside Test's Constructor\n");
  }

  ~Test(){
    printf("Inside Test's Destructor");
    getchar();
  }
};

int main() {
  static Test t1;  // Note that t1 is static

  exit(0);
}
```

Output:
Inside Test’s Constructor
Inside Test’s Destructor

Comment: Closing files isn't really a good example of an important destructor to fire when you are exiting, because files will be closed on program exit anyways.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: True, but there might exist application-level buffers that still need to be flushed.

Comment: The question does not mention C++ anywhere...

Comment: I know neither language so forgive me, but this answer makes me think exit is like C#'s failfast, so in C++ does exit in a try execute a finally?

Comment: @JimmyHoffa, c++ doesn't have `finally`

Answer (score 6):

Its worth noting that C standard (C99) defines two types of execution environments, *Freestanding Environment* and *Hosted Environment*. Freestanding environment is a C environment which does not support the C libraries and is intended for embedded applications and the like. A C environment which supports the C libraries is called a Hosted environment.

C99 says, in a Freestanding environment program termination is implementation defined. So, if the implementation defines `main`, `return n`, and `exit`, their behaviors are as is defined in that implementation.

C99 defines Hosted environment behavior as,

> If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with it, a return from the
>   initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value
>   returned by the main function as its argument; reaching the } that terminates the main
>   function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with int, the
>   termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

Comment: And it really doesn't make any sense to call exit() from a freestanding environment. The embedded equivalent of exit() would be to hang the program in an eternal loop, then wait for the watchdog to time out.

Answer (score 0):

From the C standard's perspective, not really, other than `return` being a statement and `exit()` being a function.  Either will cause any functions registered with `atexit()` to be called followed by termination of the program.

There are a couple of situations you want to watch out for:

- Recursion in `main()`.  While rarely seen in practice, it is legal in C.  (C++ explicitly forbids it.)
- Re-use of `main()`.  Sometimes an existing `main()` will be renamed something else and be called by a new `main()`.

The use of `exit()` will introduce a bug if either of those happens after you've written the code, especially if not terminating abnormally.  To avoid that, it's a good idea to be in the habit of treating `main()` as the function it is and using `return` when you want it to end.